# Create a job to sent reminders if a task is not updated in 14 days

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am working with SharePoint 2007 and have SharePoint Designer 2007. Working with that is there a way to set up an e-mail reminder when a task has not been updated for a number of days. I have been trying to set something up off of the modified date, but I have not found something that works.

Comment: Could you provide the code you tried so far? It'll greatly help on giving you the right guidance. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in solving this problem.

1). Write a custom sequential workflow to keep track of each task and email when the task modified date is greater than 14 days.

2). Write a timer job that monitors the list and iterates through the items in the list to determine which ones are past 14 days.

If you have code written I can provide more guidance